# How can i fix this error ? [overwrite/libgstreamer]

Tags: apt, 17.04

> trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbasecamerabinsrc-1.0.so.0', which is also in package libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64 1.10.4-1ubuntu1

when i try to install wine, this errors happen.
ubuntu says : try this command

> apt-get --fix-broken install
>
> apt-get install  -f

but this doesn't work also. 
so please give me the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug. There are two immediate choices, but there may be fallouts, so use them with care.

1. Force overwrite

If using apt-get:--
`sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install <name of the packge>`

Using dpkg:--
`sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite <deb package>`

2. Remove `libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64 1.10.4-1ubuntu1` and then try installing wine.